# showing a c# date in a JQuery Datepicker field

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

I'm currently building a MVC C# application. On my current webpage there are multiple textfields, all of them initialized as JQuery Datepickers. The fields are optional, though the textfields don't get filled in properly on loading the webpage. I know for a fact that the data is saved correctly in our DB, so that's no problem. Currently I got this piece of Javascript in the view:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.datepick').each(function () {
            $(this).datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });
            //$(this).val('').slice(0, -5);
        });
        //$(this).datepicker("setDate", '2010-07-25');

        @for (int i = 0; i <= listFolders.Count - 1; i++){
            string formattedDate = BusinessLogic.Domain.SecureFolderIS.giveAdecentFormattedExpireDate(listFolders[i].ExpireDate);

            @:$("#expDate-" + @(listFolders[i].LoginSecureFolderID)).datepicker("setDate", @(formattedDate));

            if (listFolders[i].ExpireDate == null || listFolders[i].ExpireDate < DateTime.Now)
            {
                @:$("#expDate-" + @(listFolders[i].LoginSecureFolderID)).datepicker("setDate", "");
            }
        }

    });
</script>
```

The static method you see there is the following:

```
    public static string giveAdecentFormattedExpireDate(DateTime? expDate)
    {            
        if (expDate != null)
        {
            DateTime tempDT = (DateTime) expDate;
            tempDT.AddMonths(1);
            return tempDT.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        }
        else
        {
            return "0001-01-01";
        }            
    }
```

In the SQL server database, the following 2 dates are saved: **2016-06-30 00:00:00**  &  **2016-05-31 00:00:00**.  The others are null and do not get displayed.

Now, the NULL values do not get displayed, which is perfect. But the actual values I put in bold above here, do not. What I see is **2020-10-20** twice. Now the final format is good of course, years-months-days, but the actual content is not. Does anyone see where I went wrong? And yes, I'm aware of [Jquery's](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate) and [C#'s custom dates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

The formattedDate I receive is 2016-09-30, which is correct, though somehow the JQuery formatter messes things up when I set the date with 2016-09-30, despite the fact they're identical in the end.

No error messages are shown.

Comment: Just did so. `formattedDate` returns the correct string, like **2016-06-30** with a c# formatter of yyyy-MM-dd

Comment: Have you tried ` return tempDT.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");`?

Comment: If you've solved it then kindly post the answer mentioning the error and how you resolved it.. and accept it as answer (after 48 hours)

Comment: Yes, I tried that (see main post), but that doesn't return a correct value. I get '2020-10-20'. I will accept an answer as soon as the problem is resolved.